# How to setup an internal keepass password server?

Tags: keepass, sharing

Our team connects to the same servers as I do.

We would like to share one keepass database for the members of that team with read and write access (and no read/write right for anyone else :-) ).

I was first thinking of a network share with read/write access to the database for our team but I'm not sure it's the best solution.

Is there another solution ?

Comment: https://keepass.info/help/base/multiuser.html seems relevant

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend self-hosting [Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/help/install-on-premise-linux/) or similar alternatives like [Keeper](https://www.keepersecurity.com/pricing/business-and-enterprise.html). While it is possible to share KeePass files with multiple-users and sync them, the added convenience and multi-user support by design fit your use-case much better. You can also utilize your org's existing RBAC / SSO solution like Azure AD, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know any opensource software for a multi-user support ?

Comment: Bitwarden's [server is open source](https://github.com/bitwarden/server). So are [their clients](https://github.com/bitwarden/clients) and [mobile apps](https://github.com/bitwarden/mobile). There is also a Rust-based reimplementation of Bitwarden's API, but I guess endorsing that for a company environment that would violate several ToS.